# how to save cloud foundry username and password?

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I can login to cloud-foundy/bluemix using:

```
cf login -u my_cf_username -p my_cf_password
```

I can set up environment variables to store these values (e.g. by setting them in `.bashrc` or `.profile`):

```
export cf_user=my_cf_username
export cf_pass=my_cf_password
cf login -u $cf_user -p $cf_pass
```

However, ideally I would like the Cloud Foundry username and password to be retrieved from a properties file, e.g. `$HOME/.cf`  - is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible with the current CF CLI client. 
It should be possible to write a [custom CF CLI Plugin](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/installcf/use-cli-plugins.html) to handle this behaviour.

Answer (score -2):

If you simply want to avoid the login step, wouldn't a bash script suffice (as suggested in [Reading username and password from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400299/reading-username-and-password-from-file) and others)?

To the larger question of how to secure credentials beyond logging into the CLI, I recommend Pat Mueller's blog entry [How your cloud application should access credentials and other private data](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/10/14/keeping-secrets-cloud-application-access-credentials-private-data/): Use a Cloud Foundry user-provided service and bind key/value to it with locally-defined VCAP. He recommends using the [cfenv package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cfenv) as shown below:

```
cfenv = require("cfenv")
var localVCAP = require("./local-vcap.json")
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv({vcap: localVCAP})
var creds  = appEnv.getServiceCreds(/session-secret/) || {}
console.log("session secret is:", creds.secret)
```

You then create a user-provided service with the `cf cups` command (*cups* = create-user-provided-service). To get access to the credentials from a given service, bind the *cups* to it. He notes several advantages of this approach; I especially like that values are only visible to users who have the appropriate access to the *cups* service. For more details, see the source article cited above.